# ${x_{k}}\rightarrow x$ in $R^n$ if and only if ${x_{k}}\cdot y\rightarrow x\cdot y$ for all $y\in R^n $

Tags: real-analysis

Show that ${x_{k}}\rightarrow x$ in $R^n$
if and only if ${x_{k}}\cdot y\rightarrow x\cdot y$
for all $y\in R^n $

I think the following:

Given the ${x_{k}}\rightarrow x$ this is equal to $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_{k}=x$, then given a $y\in R^n$, we have to:
\begin{eqnarray*}
   {x_{k}}\rightarrow x &\Leftrightarrow& \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_{k}=x\\
 &\Leftrightarrow& \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_{k} \cdot y =  x \cdot y\\
 &\Leftrightarrow& {x_{k}}\cdot y \rightarrow x \cdot y
\end{eqnarray*}

Any suggestions and comments are very helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to write the proof by the definition of convergent sequence this would be much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Remember that a sequence in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual metric) converges to a point in the space if and only if the component sequences converge.

**Hint 2**: for every $i= 1, \dots , n $ make $y = e_i$, the vector whose k-entry is 1 whereas the other entries are 0.

Edit: By a *component sequence* of $\{x_k\}$ I mean the sequence whose $k$th term is the $i$th coordinate of the point $x_k$ from the original sequence (where $i$ is some fixed integer of the set $\{1, \dots n\}$). Thus, since you are dealing with a sequence of points on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (points described with n coordinates), you can construct $n$ of those sequences.